# How can I add hypen?

Tags: python

I need correct code for the following function immediately.

def **init**(self, name, area_code, number, is_active): constructor of a telephone line:
create/initialize instance variables for name, area_code, number and is_active (default value is
True). Assume area_code is a three-digit integer with no leading 0/1; assume number is a
seven-digit integer with no leading 0/1.
 **str**: create/return a string as in this example: "703-993-1530 (GMU)"

My code is

```
class Phone(): 
    def __init__(self, name, area_code, number, is_active=True):
        self.name = name
        self.area_code = area_code
        self.number = number
        number = '%s-%s' % (self.number[:3], self.number[3:8])
        self.is_active = is_active
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.area_code) + "-" + str(self.number) + ' ' + "(" + self.name + ")"
    def __repr__(self):
        return  self.name + ','+ str(self.area_code) + ',' + str(self.number)   
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.area_code == other.area_code and self.number == other.number
    def activate(self):
        self.is_active = True
    def deactivate(self):
        self.is_active = False
```

I just need to add hypen in the phone number which I'm not getting plzzzz help someone

Comment: It is not really clear what you want. The second paragraph is hardly understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you needed?

```
class Phone(): 
    def __init__(self, name, area_code, number, is_active=True):
        self.name = name
        self.area_code = area_code
        self.number = number
        self.is_active = is_active
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.area_code) + "-" + str(self.number)[:3]+ '-'+ str(self.number)[3:] + ' ' + "(" + self.name + ")"
    def __repr__(self):
        return  self.name + ','+ str(self.area_code) + ',' + str(self.number)   
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.area_code == other.area_code and self.number == other.number
    def activate(self):
        self.is_active = True
    def deactivate(self):
        self.is_active = False
```

Now corrected: *assume number is a seven-digit integer with no leading 0/1*

Answer (score 0):

```
class Phone(): 
    def __init__(self, name, area_code, number, is_active=True):
        self.name = name
        self.area_code = area_code
        self.number = str(number)
        number = self.number[:3] + "-" + self.number[3:8]
        self.is_active = is_active
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.area_code) + "-" + str(self.number) + ' ' + "(" + self.name + ")"
    def __repr__(self):
        return  self.name + ','+ str(self.area_code) + ',' + str(self.number)   
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.area_code == other.area_code and self.number == other.number
    def activate(self):
        self.is_active = True
    def deactivate(self):
        self.is_active = False
```